# Labeling in Pie Slice in core plot iphone

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I have created a pie chart using core plot . I have attached image below for your reference.

[image]

I have used negative value of label offset so that label  be inside the pie slice . I wanted to fit label

> Dummy

in each slice properly so that they can not overlap and fit in each pie slice accordingly.

Please suggest.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 2):

This currently not supported. You can make a feature enhancement request on the Core Plot [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).

You could make custom labels and attach them to the plot using annotations. You'll have to calculate the anchor point and rotation angle for each label.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to add custom labels to plot using annotations ? My Pie chart is not fixed it can rotate. so please advise .

Comment: Look at `-[CPTPieChart positionLabelAnnotation:forIndex:]` in the Core Plot source code to see how to calculate the label anchor point and displacement. You can use the computed label angle to change the rotation angle of the label.